# Display a message every 3 days using PHP 7

Tags: php, date

I just have a problem with displaying some info once in a three days next 500 years or even more)). For example, i want to display message "Hello dear users." Thank to all.

The script under not working properly. It work only once, but i need to display it next 500 years or even more)). Thank to all.

```
<?php

   $this_day = date("d.m.Y");
   $start_date = "22.01.2019"; //-- just for example
   $display_date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($start_date. ' + 3 days'));   

    if ($this_day == $display_date) {

    echo 'Hello dear users, last time you was here 3 days ago.';

    }
     ?>
```

Comment: You have to store the date of the last visit someplace so if you aren't using and don't want to use a database look into using a cookie. But that's not likely to work in all situations but it's the best you're going to be able to do without persistent storage of some sort.

Comment: @Dave ... Sorry, but maybe i write something wrong... I need that anyone see a message, not special user or someone else... Even more... This is like advertising "module" that display some text every 3 days for all users.... $start_date - it's only for example...

Comment: You will need persistent storage somewhere to be able to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Dave Thank you for perfect answers.. Sorry, but I will rephrase. How do I display my message every 3 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create 2 dates, find the diff and if diff divisible by 3 then you can echo this message

```
$this_day = date('Y-m-d');
$start_date=date_create("2019-01-19");
$today = date_create($this_day);
$diff=date_diff($start_date,$today);
$day_diff = $diff->format("%a");
if($day_diff % 3 == 0){
    echo 'Hello dear users, last time you was here 3 days ago.';
}
```

Comment: ...Thank you, but i don't use DB... If it possible to don't use DB?

Comment: Then date_diff can be used. Editing my answer, have a look

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to display your message every third day, for which you can use the modulo operator `%`.

```php
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
  echo $i % 3, "\n";
}
```

This gives the output:

```
1
2
0
1
2
0
1
2
0
1
```

As you can see it repeats every 3 times, even as the value of `$i` increases indefinitely.

Next you need to be able to calculate a value for `$i` that is based on today's date. You can use `diff` to compare today's date with some date in the past, and that will get you a number of days that you can modulo.

Here's an example not using today's date, but instead using a date based on a for loop so you can see the pattern clearly:

```php
<?php

$reference_date = date_create("2000-01-01");

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
  $date = date_create("2019-01-$i");
  $days_since_reference = $date->diff($reference_date)->format('%a');
  $modulo = $days_since_reference % 3;
  $show_message = $modulo == 0 ? "show message :)" : "don't show message";

  echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . " : $days_since_reference : $modulo : $show_message\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
2019-01-01 : 6940 : 1 : don't show message
2019-01-02 : 6941 : 2 : don't show message
2019-01-03 : 6942 : 0 : show message :)
2019-01-04 : 6943 : 1 : don't show message
2019-01-05 : 6944 : 2 : don't show message
2019-01-06 : 6945 : 0 : show message :)
2019-01-07 : 6946 : 1 : don't show message
2019-01-08 : 6947 : 2 : don't show message
2019-01-09 : 6948 : 0 : show message :)
2019-01-10 : 6949 : 1 : don't show message
```

Comment: YES YES YES... You understand me perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

change `if ($this_day == $display_date) {` to `if ($this_day >= $display_date) {`

take a look at [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) for options

Comment: But it would display all time after $display_date, but i need to display ONLY once in a 3 days  till the next 50 years.